# How to send the same data from the server to all clients using TCP/IP in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

How to send the same data from the server to all clients using TCP/IP in java in socket multithreading?

I've tried to **send an array from the first client to the server**, **the second client send an array to the server**.

Whene the server **accepted two clients**, it will **merge the two arrays** in one array and sorted it, **then send it as a response to the two clients**.

**The codes:**

**The Server.java file:**

```
   import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Server
{
       public static void main(String[] zero) throws InterruptedException
       {
               ServerSocket socket;
               int nb = 0;

               try { 

                        socket = new ServerSocket(6789,2);
                        //creé le thread  
                        Thread t = new Thread(new Accepter_clients(socket,nb));
                        t.start();

                        System.out.println("Mes employeurs sont prêts !");
                   } 

               catch (IOException e) 
                   {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                   }
       }
}

//**********************************************************************************
//**********************************************************************************

class Accepter_clients implements Runnable 
{
           private ServerSocket socketserver;
           private Socket socket;
           private int nbrclient ;
        //  private Boolean etat=Boolean.FALSE;
           ObjectOutputStream out;
           ObjectInputStream in ;
           int []  tableauAEmettre ;
           List<Object> liste = new ArrayList<Object>();



     public Accepter_clients(ServerSocket s,int nb)
      {
           this.socketserver = s;
           this.nbrclient=nb;
           System.out.println("serveur n :"+nbrclient);
      }


     public  void run() //pour un seul thread à la fois
    {

         try {


             while(true)
              {
                this.socket = socketserver.accept(); // Un client se connecte onl'accepte
                System.out.println("Le client numéro "+nbrclient+" est connecté !");
                nbrclient++;
                this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());

                    //System.out.println("serveur envoi: " + tabl);
                read();

                write();

                    this.socket.close();

               }

         }
         catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }
     public synchronized void read() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
     {  

         this.in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
         Object objetRecu= this.in.readObject();
         tableauAEmettre= (int[]) objetRecu;

        for( int i=0;i<tableauAEmettre.length;i++){
            liste.add(tableauAEmettre[i]);
        }
            System.out.println("serveur recoit depuis Client: "+ (nbrclient-1) +" : "+ liste);
            this.notify();



     }

     public synchronized void write()
     {  


         try {
             System.out.println("Je suis la !!!");
             this.wait();
             Object tt = liste.toArray();
             int[] t = (int[]) tt ;
             Arrays.sort(t);
            // List<Object> tabl=tri(liste);
             System.out.println("Je suis la hihihih !!!");

             this.out.writeObject(t);
             this.out.flush();
             this.notify();
        } 
         catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.getMessage();
        } 
         catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.getMessage();
        }

     }


//Fonction permet de trie les tableau
}
```

**The Client.java file:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] zero) throws ClassNotFoundException{

        Socket socket;
        ObjectInputStream in;
        ObjectOutputStream out ;

        try {
                socket = new Socket("localhost",6789);

                out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.flush();

                int lower = 3;
                int higher = 15;

                int random = (int)(Math.random() * (higher-lower)) + lower;
                int[] tableauAEmettre= new int[random];

                for (int i=0;i<random;i++)
                {
                    tableauAEmettre[i]=(int)(Math.random() * (40-0)) + 0;
                }

                out.writeObject(tableauAEmettre);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Client 1 envoi: " + Arrays.toString(tableauAEmettre));

                 in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                 Object objetRecu = in.readObject();
                 int[] tableauRecu = (int[]) objetRecu;
                 System.out.println("Client 1 recoit: " + Arrays.toString(tableauRecu));

                 in.close();
                 out.close();
                 socket.close();
                 socket.close();

            } 
        catch (IOException e) 
           {
                 e.printStackTrace();
           }
     }
}
```

**The Client2.java file:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Client2 {

    public static void main(String[] zero) throws ClassNotFoundException{

        Socket socket;
        ObjectInputStream in;
        ObjectOutputStream out ;

        try {
                socket = new Socket("localhost",6789);

                out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.flush();

                int lower = 3;
                int higher = 15;

                int random = (int)(Math.random() * (higher-lower)) + lower;
                 int[] tableauAEmettre= new int[random];

                for (int i=0;i<random;i++)
                {
                    tableauAEmettre[i]=(int)(Math.random() * (40-0)) + 0;
                }

                out.writeObject(tableauAEmettre);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Client 2 envoi: " + Arrays.toString(tableauAEmettre));

                 in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                 Object objetRecu = in.readObject();
                 int[] tableauRecu = (int[]) objetRecu;
                 System.out.println("Client 2 recoit: " + Arrays.toString(tableauRecu));

                 in.close();
                 out.close();
                 socket.close();
                 socket.close();

            } 
        catch (IOException e) 
           {
                 e.printStackTrace();
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: It depends what method of sockets you're using. Is it a library? Custom made?

Comment: Do you already have a server and multiple clients are able to connect to it? (which part are you having trouble with?) Posting code will help you receive a better answer more quickly.

Comment: Check out ZeroMq, it supports pub/sub over sockets.

Comment: UDP Multicast might be an option. Depends on where your clients are. How far away are clients?
Broadcast on a UDP Address and all clients who want to listen to that address receive the information by subscribing.

Comment: @Tony Probably not the best idea to suggest UDP, which drops packets, when the OP asked for TCP.

Comment: You need to create a thread for each client socket.  Don't try to read or write to a socket with the acceptor thread as this will prevent you accepting more connections.

Comment: Hate the spanish comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want the accepting connection thread to be seperate from the reading and writing, as suggested by Peter Lowry.
My examples are very stripped down and will require more code to work correctly, but should be enough to illustrate.

Would help to have some class to help manage the socket

```
Class Connection {//possibly implements runnable
    Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    ObjectOutputStream out;

    public Connection(Socket s) {
        this.socket = s;
        this.in = s.getInputStream();
        this.out = s.getOutputStream();
    }

    public void sendData(Object o)
    {
        out.sendObject(o);
    }
}
```

and in the main function.. Sets up the accepting thread and has the server loop for reading and writing.

```
main(String[] zero) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    ArrayList<Connection> connections = new ArrayList<Connection>();
    //...
    Thread t = new Thread(new Accepter_clients(connections));
    t.start();

    //Server read/write loop
    boolean continue = true;
    while (continue)
    {
        synchronized(connections)
        {
            for (Connection c : connections)
            {
                //c.sendData();
            }

            for (Connection c : connections)
            {
                //c.readData();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally your acceptor thread... Watches and adds new connections to the connection list.

```
ArrayList<Connection> connections;
public Accepter_clients(ArrayList<Connection> connections)
  {
      this.connections = connections;
  }

public void run()
{
    ServerSocket s; //initialize here
    while (true) //some boolean to continue instead
    {
        //...
        Connection newConn = new Connection(s.accept);
        synchronized (connections) { //cant modify list while using it elsewhere
            connections.add(newConn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a specific question on part of it or some type of error I would be more than happy to expand on something.

Comment: There is an exception: the address is already used in JVM after executing the first client.

Comment: Edited the acceptor_client, you'll want to make sure the ServerSocket is above the `while()` loop. It should only be set once because then while it isn't closed that socket/port is used up.

Comment: The same problem, i can't send to all clients :/

Comment: make sure you are creating the ServerSocket above, not just declaring it like in my code. I will be leaving for the weekend however, so you may wish to post a new question if you still are having problems.

Comment: Where i can close the the connexion, out and in?

Comment: I would have a try/catch/finally block over the loop, which closes the connections in the finally{} block.